How to get rid of phantom, orphan network interfaces on macOS 15?
I have some ghost/orphan network interfaces on my Mac Mini M1 2020 (macOS 15.1) that I would like to clean up. They appear in several places, such as in the Internet Sharing System Settings pane, as well as in the Terminal output of networksetup -listallhardwareports.

Running the command below reveals these network interfaces, several of which no longer physically exist:
networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '
/^Hardware/{sub("Hardware Port: ","",$0); n=$0}
/^Device/{sub("Device: ","",$0); d=$0}
/^Ethernet/{sub("Ethernet Address: ","",$0); m=$0}
/^$/ && n!="" && m!="" && d!="" {
  printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n",d,m,n
  n=m=d=""
}' | sort

Output
en0 14:98:77:64:11:0d   Ethernet
en1 14:98:77:5a:8b:1b   Wi-Fi
en2 36:32:32:20:15:00   Thunderbolt 1
en3 36:32:32:20:15:04   Thunderbolt 2
en4 82:03:9a:33:94:72   Ethernet Adapter (en4)
en5 82:03:9a:33:94:73   Ethernet Adapter (en5)
en9 00:e0:4c:68:13:10   USB 10/100/1000 LAN

In my case, en2, en3, en4, en5 and en9 do not exist. I would like to purge them. I have tried deleting the NetworkInterfaces.plist plist using
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInterfaces.plist

However that does not make them go away. Related question with no answer: How do I get rid of old, orphaned network hardware ports under macOS?

Try editing this file:
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist

I wouldn't recommend deleting it, as you'll have to redo quite a bit of configuration.

Tried that, sadly it does not survive a reboot for some reason.

I should have checked this before answering, but I have the same phantom interfaces as you on two different Macs; in fact, I have more of them. I'm not sure why they're there, but the condition seems to be normal and I don't see any reason to worry about it.
